# Images from the facebook api are not large as they appear in facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook apis to get the news feed data of user.  I am able to get the images but they are very small in size, so when I keep `wrap_content` they are very small.

When I fix the size to some 150dp width and height 100dp they are losing clarity.

How can I maintain the clarity and size of image as they appear in facebook.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly what images are you loading? For certain enpoints and tables, there are fields that you can use to specify the image size.

Comment: I got the images from news feed url of facebook api https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=xxxxxx. I tried to get posted pictutes of my friends,but I am getting very small images.But for getting profile picture ,there is an url where we can get the images of our own size.I just want to know whether any other url to get the posted pictures also.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and height in the URL.

For example:

- 150x100 http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?width=150&height=100
- 250x250 http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?width=250&height=250

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I am asking about the posted pictures information.I got this from the picture field of news feed url.    https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=

Comment: Can you post an example of a picture URL you're looking at? Looks like some of them (starting with https://s-platform.ak.fbcdn.net/www/app_full_proxy.php) give you the full size if you just parse the src parameter from the URL.